# Asterisk ODBC show is empty

Tags: sql-server, linux, asterisk

I'm new to Asterisk and I'm trying to connect asterisk to MS SQL server as I knew that Asterisk +  DB will be very powerful. I followed the same steps in Asterisk™: The Definitive Guide (Asterisk book)
http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/installing_configuring_odbc.html#Database_id246915

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC for MSSQL
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount = 1
Fileusage = 1
Threading = 2
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[MSSQL]
Description  = MSSQL Database
Driver = FreeTDS
Database = asterisk
Server = 192.168.14.193
Username = sa
Password = iti
Trace = no
TDS_Version = 8.0
Port = 1433
```

when I use this statement

```
echo "select 1" | isql -v MSSQL
```

I got

```
[s1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[s1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

but when I used this `echo "select 1" | isql -v MSSQL sa iti`
it worked

continuing the tutorial

I recompiled Asterisk to feel the changes after installing unixODBC
I modified the res_odbc.conf file

/etc/asterisk/res_odbc.conf

```
[asterisk]
    enabled => yes
    dsn => MSSQL
    username => sa
    password => iti
    pooling => no
    pre-connect => yes
```

I also Modified Freetds.conf

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[MSSQL]
Server = 192.168.14.193
TDS_Version = 8.0
Port = 1433
```

when I use odbc show I got this

```
*CLI> odbc show

ODBC DSN Settings
-----------------

*CLI>
```

I have already checked the res_odbc, func_odbc while I make menu select
I am using MS SQL Server 2014 installed on my machine and Ubuntu 16 desktop

Please help me solve the issue and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have setup connection in res_config_odbc.conf in asterisk directory(seams like you missed that step)

You can test that by

```
asterisk -rvv
module unload res_config_odbc.so
module load res_config_odbc.so
```

Comment: I cannot find the res_config_odbc.conf do I have to create it ?

Comment: try commands above, if it say "no res_config_odbc.conf" then move res_odbc.conf to res_config_odbc.conf

Comment: See error which supply set above. Remmember, SO is question's site, debug is OT here.

Comment: why was I not able to read the username (UID) and password (PWD) from odbc.ini?

Answer (score 0):

In odbc.ini file, the username key should be UID and not Username.

See: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm

Try it then validate with:

```
echo "select 1" | isql -v MSSQL
```

Comment: @arheops I'm pretty sure the file in asterisk is /etc/asterisk/res_odbc.conf not res_config_odbc.conf

Comment: I used UID but still could not connect without using the username and password